# Display Boolean Values to Material Table React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am implementing a Material Table event log. The data this event log receives is 'string' & 'boolean' values. I can display the string values, But, I only can display either all true or all false. I cant figure out how to get the true and false values to display correctly.

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <StyledTableRow>
          {data[0] &&
            columns.map((heading) => <TableCell>{heading}</TableCell>)}
        </StyledTableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {data.map((row) => (
          <TableRow>
            {columns.map((column) => (
              <TableCell>
                {typeof row[column] === 'boolean' && false
                  ? 'False'
                  : typeof row[column] === 'boolean' && true
                  ? 'True'
                  : row[column]}
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
```

Comment: Just use `row[column].toString()`

Comment: In one line solution `{typeof row[column] === 'boolean' ? row[column].toString() : row[column]}`

Answer (score 0):

Your ternaries need a tweak. For example:

```
 typeof row[column] === 'boolean' && false
```

will always evaluate to `false`. It looks like you mean:

```
  typeof row[column] === 'boolean' && row[column]===false
```

and so on for the others.

Though I should point out you don't need the first typeof comparison at all - you can just do:

```
 {row[column] === false ? 'False' 
                        : row[column] === true
                        ? 'True' 
                        : row[column]}
```

Comment: @ Will Jenkins That worked perfectly!!!

Comment: @PeterM. Glad I could help - can you accept my answer please?